# How to create a folder and a file in my project root directory

Tags: vb.net, file, directory, relative-path

I have a vb .net application which is stored in my D: drive. I need to create a folder and a file in my project root directory. I used the following code to create the folder as well as the file.

```
 If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists("\test\")) Then
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("\test\")
                If (Not System.IO.File.Exists("\test\output.txt")) Then
                    System.IO.File.Create("\test\output.txt")
                End If
            End If
```

But the folder and the file is created in C: drive.
I used `Dim fullpath As String = Path.GetFullPath("\test\output.txt")` to identify where the file and folder is created.

I want to create it in my project root directory. That means I need to create the folder using a relative path criteria.

Comment: Did any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the directory of the executable or dll of your running application then:

```
   Dim spath As String
        spath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( _
                   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)
        If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(spath, "test"))) Then

            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(spath, "test"))

            If (Not System.IO.File.Exists(Path.Combine(spath, "test\output.txt"))) Then

                System.IO.File.Create(Path.Combine(spath, "test\output.txt"))
            End If
        End If
```

If you want the solution/project directory then:

---

```
        Dim spath As String = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory

        If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(spath, "test"))) Then
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(spath, "test"))
            If (Not System.IO.File.Exists(Path.Combine(spath, "test\output.txt"))) Then
                System.IO.File.Create(Path.Combine(spath, "test\output.txt"))
            End If
        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this path, and work from there...

```
    MsgBox(Application.StartupPath)
```